# cannot use wildfly 8080 port with amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables, wildfly

I try to open port 8080 on which Wildfly is running. I have already modified security group connected with my instance in a way that inbound and outbound traffic is allowed using tcp 8080 from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0). Running telnet localhost 8080 results in:

telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.

After wget localhost:8080 I receive index.html with "Welcome to WildFly Application Server 8". Ip tables are configured with policy ACCEPT for both INPUT and OUTPUT. There are no additional rules. Firewall is inactive. Running nmap xxx -p 8080 gives information that this particular port is closed. And what is expected an attempt to display site via ip-address:8080 in browser ends up with information that it can't be accessed. I'm stuck. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've managed to make it work. As it turned out the problem was that wildfly did not have ip address bind properly set up. The solution was to run wildfly with "-b ip_address" option.

Answer (score 4):

Binding all IP addresses to the wildfly as below solved the problem for me:

```
./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```