# AWS EC2 running a server on 8080 but cannot connect from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, smalltalk, vast, seaside

Here is a shot of my inbound rules[image]

I should be able to connect using the domain that is up and running so I can get the index page at http://www.marblecake.net but I can't get my server at http://www.marblecake.net:8080. (My server is a Smalltalk Seaside server running under VAST 11)

I can run the server locally using localhost:8080. I have the same problem with FTP in that I can't connect externally (I have removed ftp server for now so don't check that one).

Can anyone explain what I have to do further to get to connect to my AWS server please?

Comment: Have you checked both the security groups of the instance and the network access control lists of the subnet in the VPC?

Comment: Also check to which IP address your Smalltalk server binds. SO shows me several questions related to this on the right, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491558/cannot-connect-to-website-running-on-a-node-server-at-aws-ec2-instance?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294819/cannot-use-wildfly-8080-port-with-amazon-ec2?rq=1

Comment: It was simple. Windows Defender needed the ports to be opened!